# Why I cannot preview image uploaded by inputfield and show it in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need to upload an image and show it in canvas in browser. First time when I upload this image, canvas width and height are zero, but second time the image is appearing correctly? Why?

```js
function previewFile() {
        const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        const img = document.createElement('img');
        const file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();
      
        reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
            img.src = reader.result;
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
        }, false);
      
        if (file) {
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }
```

```html
           <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./script.js"></script>
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you setting the image src, it doesn't loaded synchonous, so you have to wait for image load event, and only then draw it on the canvas.

A lot of operations in JS connected with resources are of asynchronous nature, so you have to deal with it.

```js
function previewFile() {
        const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        const img = document.createElement('img');
        const file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();
      
        reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
            img.src = reader.result;
            img.onload = function() {
                canvas.width = img.width;
                canvas.height = img.height;
                canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
            }
        }, false);
      
        if (file) {
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }
```

```html
           <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./script.js"></script>
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </body>
    </html>
```